# Solr dateRangeField fetch exact data considering only dates and without considering time

Tags: solr, date-range

1) In solr 6,I have dateRange fieldType

`<fieldType name="daterange" class="solr.DateRangeField"/>`

2) This contains availableDateRange of a hotel lodge rooms.

```
"availableDateRange":["[2017-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z]"],
```

3) When I query to get all Available hotel rooms for whole 2017 year with following query

```
fq={!field f=dateRange op=Contains}[2017 TO 2017]
```

4) I am getting only rooms which are also available on 2018-01-01, I mean I am getting only records which has dateRange endDate+1

```
[2017-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z]
```

> I know This problem can be solved if I can save end date as
>
> ```
> "availableDateRange":["[2017-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2017-12-31T23:59:59Z]"],
> ```
>
> OR change the endDate in query itself, i.e. EndDate-1
>
> due to some reason I can not do above two approach

Does anyone knows any settings or any change in query (#3 in my question) so I will get following record.

```
"availableDateRange":["[2017-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z]"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of operation `Contains`, you should use `Within`, which will do the trick for you.

I did the query: `fq={!field f=date op=Within}[2017 TO 2017]` and it returns to me document with range `[2017-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2017-12-31T00:00:00Z]` and with range `[2017-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2017-12-31T23:59:59Z]`

Full source of the example is [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene6/src/main/scala/DateRangeHotels.scala).